AttributeError: property 'mode' of 'JpegImageFile' object has no setter
I'm getting an error:
AttributeError: property 'mode' of 'JpegImageFile' object has no setter
While trying to open an image using the Pillow library.
My code:
from pil import Image as pl
my_img = pl.open(file_name)

What does it mean?

If you can, you should place a link to the problematic image file.Of course for everyone and ordinary jpegs that works.

It is about pillow lybrary dependencies.
It works after a reinstallation.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
